# fs.createReadStream is not a function in a local instance

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, fs, vs-extensibility

So I want to work with BinaryData. The code I wrote is basically the example given on the homepage: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatereadstreamoptions

```
import * as fsp from 'fs/promises';

const filePath = "C:\\some\\binary\\file"

const parseStream = async (path: string) => {

    let fileHandle
    try {
        fileHandle = await fsp.open(path, 'r')
        const stream = fileHandle.createReadStream()
        console.log(stream.bytesRead)
        
    } catch (error ){
        console.log(error)

    }finally {
        await fileHandle?.close()
    }

}

export {filePath, parseStream}
```

But it throws the error:

> 'fileHandle.createReadStream is not a function'

I double-checked that it is node 17.3 that I'm useing. Since fs is a node core module it only exists in the compilled node.exe.

intellisense picks up the method, but of course this is due to having installed @types/node.
Also it runs locally and not in a browser, in a browser the whole fs module is missing. So it would throw an error when trying to import. The code runs in a debug window of visual studio code as part of an extension.

Comment: you may want to check your node version as `fileHandle.createReadStream` is added in node 16

Comment: Why don't you just use `fs.createReadStream(path)` instead of first creating a fileHandle?

Comment: That's a mystery because this code works in my node v16.13.0  (plain JS, no TypeScript).  My best guess is that you aren't running the nodejs version you think you are.

Comment: Does not work on Node.js v16.9.1.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this feature was added to the Node.js v16 series in v16.11.  I'm not quite sure how the odd-numbered test versions (v17) are branched, but I'm guessing v17.3 was forked from a version prior to v16.11 and Node.js docs missed this.

I would try a later v17.x release.

https://nodejs.org/docs/v16.10.0/api/fs.html#promises-api
https://nodejs.org/docs/v16.11.0/api/fs.html#promises-api